# SQL syntax highlighting and code completion in Eclipse PDT

Tags: php, eclipse, syntax-highlighting, sql, ide

Is there a way of enabling highlighting (and/or code completion for SQL) for SQL syntax in PHP strings variable while developing some PHP works related to SQL using Eclipse PDT?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such option and currently no Eclipse plug-in exists which provides this feature.

However that does not mean such a feature would be impossible to build.